# Save only unique (by property value) records in database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

My EF entity class looks like:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public int DataPointId {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
    public double Value {get; set;}
}
```

where `DataPointId` is PK, no other columns are indexed at the time.

Let's say that we have a collection of DataPoints which must be added into `context.DataPoints` database table:

```
var dpToAdd = new List<DataPoint>{ /* 10000 different dp's */ };
```

But, I want to save in db only those `DataPoint's` which are unique when it comes to its `DateTime` column. 
For example: one of `DataPoint` in dpToAdd has `DateTime = 01/01/2016 00:00:00` - if `context.DataPoints` already contains DataPoint with the same `DateTime` value, this point should be ignored.

`context.DataPoints` table can have like 1 million of records, and at a single request there can be collection of 10-50k of records that needs to be verified before saving in db.

How to handle such process so that the performance is the best possible?

My first though about this is to create an index on `DateTime` column and then, for every `DataPoints` that is about to be added check something like:

1: simply loop thru all points collection and check which needs to be added

```
foreach (var dp in dpToAdd)
{
    // with Any()
    if !(context.DataPoints.Any(p => p.DateTime == dp.DateTime))
    {
        context.DataPoints.Add(dp);
    }

    // or with Contains()
    if !(context.DataPoints.Select(p => p.DateTime).Contains(dp.DateTime))
    {
        context.DataPoints.Add(dp);
    }
}
```

2: get the `DateTime` values which already occurs in database, and exclude them from db addition

```
var common = context.DataPoints.Select(p => p.DateTime).Intersect(dpToAdd.Select(d => d.DateTime));
var reallyToAdd = dpToAdd.Where(p => !common.Contains(p.DateTime));
context.DataPoints.AddRange(reallyToAdd);
```

Do you have any other suggestions if this task can be developed in any other, better way?

Comment: 2 is okay. What sql engine are you using? You maybe able to use `MERGE` if you are on sql server

Comment: Yes, SQL server here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have so big table and large data to insert, for performance reason, you should create helping intermediate table `DataPointHelper` with same columns plus `Guid`. First, you will insert data to this table, and then will fetch rows from it which not exist at `DataPoints` table, and then will insert them into `DataPoints`. `Guid` property is needed for *transactional* correctness:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var data = dpToAdd.Select(x => new DataPointHelper 
{
    DateTime = x.DateTime,
    Value = x.Value,
    Guid = guid
}).ToList();
context.DataPointHelpers.AddRange(data);//it is better to use BulkInsert
context.SaveChanges();

var toInsert = (from x in context.DataPointHelpers
                where x.Guid == guid
                join y in context.DataPoints on x.DateTime equals y.DateTime into subs
                from sub in subs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where sub == null
                select x.DateTime).ToList();

if(toInsert.Count > 0)
{
    var toInsertData = dpToAdd.Where(x => toInsert.Contains(x.DateTime)).ToList();
    context.DataPoints.AddRange(toInsertData);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Sure, you should to create unique indexes for `DateTime` property at both tables.

So you have only three round trips to database instead of thousands or instead of executing query like: `where DateTime in (thousands values)`, moreover `in` statement has limit.

Comment: Thanks, so DataPointHelpers table will be kind of temporary table, I will insert there a series of DataPoints that are requested to be added to `DataPoints` table and then I have to verify and filter out points that actually should be stored in `DataPoints` table. But, after each datapoints insert operation in `DataPointHelpers` - should't it be cleared?

Comment: It is not necessary to clear table, because you have additional condition: `where x.Guid == guid`, so you will not deal with items from another iterations. But, if you want, you should delete items `where x.Guid == guid`.

Comment: You are right but I think about db size - it will be almost doubled because in a fact we will have always DataPoints doubled - i think that the temporary table should be cleared after every datapoints series addition.

Comment: Ok, at this case, you can do this: `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"delete from DataPointHelpers where Guid = {guid}");`

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use this:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
    var ls = new List<DataPoint>();
    ls.Add(new DataPoint { DataPointId =1, Value = 1, DateTime = dt});
    ls.Add(new DataPoint { DataPointId =2, Value = 2, DateTime = dt});
    ls.Add(new DataPoint { DataPointId =1, Value = 1, DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)});

    var distincData = ls.GroupBy(l => l.DateTime).Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: var distincData = ls.GroupBy(l => l.DateTime).Select(g => g.Key); would be better for faster results

Comment: I'm not sure what context.DataPoints.Add(dp); does, but i think it could be (assuming that Add it could have some logic inside that we dont know).
But i think you can test it with a timer.